# 'Refreshing' SSRS subscriptions (subquestion: how to access report execution times in ReportServer db?)

Tags: database, t-sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence, subscription

In a place where I work we have lots of subscriptions set for SSRS reports. Some reports have as many as 100 subscriptions set up.

Our data warehouse is refreshed every night, with all the data being dropped and loaded in again.

Because of that, on occasion when things go wrong and the data isn't loaded up in the morning when the subscriptions are supposed to run, they are unable to fill in the parameters and get bugged like this:

```
The subscription contains parameter values that are not valid.
```

Now to fix them, we have to manually open every subscription and hit save again. Sometimes this is not enough and we have to manually set up every parameter again. This is very frustrating and time consuming. So this brings me to my question:

How to prevent this? Is there a way to automatically 'refresh' all subscriptions? Other solution I have thought of, but lack the knowledge of ReportServer db to execute is:

Perhaps run a script before the subscriptions are set to execute. The script would check if data exists in warehouse database tables. If there is no data, delay subscriptions for an hour and then try again. Is this doable? If it is, I would be extremely grateful for a query that gives me access to execution times of subscriptions. I tried and couldn't build one myself. [The more I think of it the more I think that this would be the best solution, so please if anyone knows how to access subscription execution times in ReportServer db - let me know!]

Any other solutions are extremely welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can adjust the jobs for the subscriptions. You can ad steps (to check for data) and set retries on them as per usual. However: When updating a subscription on the report server the job will be deleted and another one generated. thus making any changes you did in regard of the subscription obsolete.

Comment: Would it be possible to just delete all jobs (subscriptions) and create them again with the previously set parameters? As I said the problem is very rare, but then very time consuming to repair.  Something obviously goes south because it loses the parameters data, but perhaps I could make a subscriptions backup and then just drop them all and reload as needed, when the problem occurs? I think this boils down to whether or not the chosen parameters info is stored in a database as well - I guess it should be?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible. I can't test it here since we don't use SSRS on this location thus the tables are empty. If it is possible I recon it should be somewhere in these tables:
 `SELECT 
   *
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule a 
   JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs b
            ON a.ScheduleID = b.name
            JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule c
            ON b.name = c.ScheduleID
            JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions d
            ON c.SubscriptionID = d.SubscriptionID
            JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog e
            ON d.report_oid = e.itemid`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this once I get permissions to access msdb.dbo.sysjobs